# Add Model Project (EntityFramwork) to Asp.net Core 3 Project

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor

I have 3 projects in my Solution like below:

1. ModelProject (EntityFramework)
2. ProjectA (ASP.NET MVC)
3. ProjectB (ASP.NET CORE 3 with Blazor)

So in model project i defined my tables ,relations, queries and their classes then added that on ProjectA and ProjectB.

on ProjectB (.net core) in startup.cs by services.AddDbContext tries to add dbcontext (ModelProject) but get this error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'ServiceLifetime' because it is not a delegate type

Is this error for using EF on Core Project? how can i solve it?

ProjectB (Core):

```
services .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer() .AddDbContext<Models.DataContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataContext")); });
```

and dbcontext (EntityFramework Standard):

```
namespace ModelProject
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext() : base("DataContext")
        {          
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext, Migrations.Configuration>());
            (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior = true;
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 300;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: please add you dbcontext class code

Comment: Please add the code that throwing this exception. Without seeing your code how can we be able find your problem?

Comment: code added to question. I have a Model project (EF) that I want use on all of other projects in my solution. but can't use that in .net core project!

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be:

```
.AddDbContext<Models.DataContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataContext")));
```

In other words, *without* the curly brackets. You could alternatively just return the `options` instance, but that's all just unnecessary code-bloat. The exception is a red herring. Because your lambda currently is essentially an action (no return) rather than a func, it's not matching the right param for `AddDbContext`.

Comment: I replace this code but not work!
 https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/10/2/c3d58c2d3c5b15708feb643d570e2ef8-full.jpg